# Decreasing Tensorflow Serving docker image size

Tags: tensorflow, java-native-interface, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to build a TFServing docker image that is less than 1GB in size. If you follow the online [instructions](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/docker) you get an image that is about 16GB in size. You can however decrease the size to 3.5GB if you only build the model server

```
bazel build //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server
```

Half the footprint is from the dynamic lib build products in core/kernels

```
root@5c275ce482e3:/# du -h -d 1  bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/
780M    bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs
1.8G    bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/
```

I think this can be made much smaller since the Tensorflow Java API links to a dylib that is only 90MB (GPU)/30MB (CPU). Looking at the Bazel BUILD files it seems both the JNI/dylib and model_servers targets depends on all_kernels. I don't understand why the dylib for JNI is so small. How can I get the tfserver build to be of a comparable size?

Comment: I would like to see a small tfserving docker image myself. I built one that's around 2.6GB still big, but smaller than 3.5.

It's public and available if you want to use it to serve models.
https://hub.docker.com/r/epigramai/model-server/